# Entity Framework asp.net mvc5- Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection

I am trying to do

```
IList<Sth> sths= Context.Sth.Where(g => g.IsX == true && g.Y.Name== "name").ToList();  //here it successfully compares  g.Y.Name
            foreach (Sth g in sths)
            {
                Context.Entry(g).Collection(g=>g.Y).Load(); //the exception is thrown here
                this.mylist.Add(g.Y.Id);
            }
```

I already tried

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
```

.

Comment: Apparently `g.Y` is not `ICollection<>`. Use either `.Reference` method (instead of `.Collection`) or better why not eager load it in the main query with `Include`.

Comment: You can include sub entities on the main query using `Include`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g.Y`is not a collection otherwise you wouldn't be able to call `g.Y.Name` on the first line. So you should either use `Reference` instead of collection, or preferably use [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-2.1) instead. For example:

```
IList<Sth> sths = Context.Sth
    .Where(g => g.IsX == true && g.Y.Name== "name")
    .Include(g => g.Y)
    .ToList(); 

this.mylist.AddRange(sths.Select(g => g.Y.Id);
```

But, if all you are trying to do it get the `Id` property, then you can just do that:

```
this.mylist.AddRange(Context.Sth
    .Where(g => g.IsX == true && g.Y.Name== "name")
    .Select(g => g.Y.Id));
```

Comment: thanks! But than, I had to change the IList to IQueryable :)